# Logical error in max and min implementation?

Tags: python, minmax

I know there is a min max syntax but I just wanted to do it myself using if but the code i wrote keep returning `0 0` where is my mistake at?
The program is supposed to print out larges and least number from a space separated numbers input

```
user = input(" :) ")

user = user.split(' ')

lt = 0
gt = 0
gtn = 0
ltn = 0

for i in user:
    for j in range(0, len(user)):
        if int(i) < int(user[j]):
            lt += 1
        elif int(i) > int(user[j]):
            gt += 1
        else:
            pass
    if lt == len(user):
        ltn = i
    elif gt == len(user):
        gtn = i

print(gtn, ltn)
```

Comment: plz add some sample input output

Comment: What is it supposed to do?

Comment: `lt` will never be equal to `len(user)`, as `if int(i) < int(user[j])` will always fail when `user(j)` is `i`

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a nested `for`, neither so many `if` conditions. All you have to do is initialize `min` to a very large value and `max` to a very small value then iterate once.

```
nums = map(int, input(" :) ").split())
min_n = float('inf')
max_n = -float('inf')

for n in nums:
    if n < min_n:
        min_n = n
    if n > max_n:
        max_n = n

print(min_n)
print(max_n)
```

Sample output:

```
:) 3 4 5 6 2 11 2 3 4 99 1 -1
-1
99
```

Comment: hey that really worked but I am having a hard time understanding float(inf) and -float(inf)?

Comment: @moyemo See here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34264710/what-is-the-point-of-floatinf-in-python