# How to get min value between limits?

Tags: python, python-3.x, lambda, min

### Introduction to the problem

I have a list of numbers and I want to, given certain value, get the closest value in the list that fulfil the condition. This is: the difference between closest value and value itself should be less than 0.5

### What have I done

I'm new with lambda expressions so may be I don't understand the working process of this function.
I have based (copy) my code on this answer:
[from list of integers, get number closest to a given value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12141150/from-list-of-integers-get-number-closest-to-a-given-value)

```
def min_in_limits(value,list):
    new_val = min(list, key=lambda x: float(abs(float(x)-float(value)))<0.5)
    return new_val
```

So, when I give these inputs:

```
list = [9,11,13]
value = 8.9
```

Function min_in_limits returns 11, instead of 9

When evaluating step by step lambda returns:

```
True, False, False
```

Why is this failing?

### Less elegant, but functional

```
def less_elegant(value,list):
    dictionary = {}
    for i in list:
        temp = float(abs(float(i)-float(value)))
        if temp < 0.5:
            dictionary.update({temp:i})
    keys = dictionary.keys()
    return(dictionary[min(keys)])
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a one liner you could use. Assuming `l=[9, 11, 13]` and `v=8.9` you could use the following:

```
min(map(lambda x: x if float(abs(float(x) - float(v))) < 0.5 else float('inf'), l))
```

Here we are mapping all of the values of `l` that do not satisfy our condition to infinity. Then we take the smallest value by using the min function.

Comment: Thank you, a nice solution for the problem. Now I have to check this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34264710/what-is-the-point-of-floatinf-in-python to understand float('inf') :)

Comment: Happy to help!. `float('inf')` is just a really big float number. There is no way the condition `float('inf') - any_number < 0.5` will be `True` since subtracting from infinity is infinity (again).

Answer (score 2):

`key` in `min` is used to *remap* values when comparing them. Current value is passed to the function given as `key`, and its output is used when comparing objects, instead of original objects. If you add `< 0.5` to that function, instead of the distance as a number, you will be returning only a boolean flag that tells you if your number *is close*.

What you could use instead is this:

```
def min_in_limits(value, list_):
    value = float(value)  # if it is e.g. string
    new_val = min(list_, key=lambda x: abs(float(x) - value))
    if abs(new_val - value) < 0.5:
        return new_val
    return None
```

After you find your minimum, check if it is within your threshold of `0.5` and return `None` if it is not, meaning no value in `list_` is close enough. Instead of hardcoding `0.5`, you could pass it as a function argument.

You should be passing `value` which is `float` and `list_` which is a list of `float`s or `int`s, in which case you can remove `value = float(value)` and replace `float(x)` with just `x`.

Furthermore, please do not use keywords (e.g. `list`) as variable/parameter names.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and explanation, In my code I usually use Spanish words for variables (lista in this case), thus I avoid the use of keywords. Anyway thank you for your advice

Answer (score 1):

In addition to [@Luka's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62039777/) and because you were using `dict.update` in a `for` loop, you can also use a *[dictionary comprehension](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/)* to perform the same operation if necessary :

```py
def min_in_limits(value, li):
    value = float(value)
    d = {abs(i - value): i for i in li if abs(i - value) < 0.5}
    # `d` might be an empty dict
    return d[min(d.keys())] if d else None
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to write the functions, but I can shortly explaination why your original codes fail, in case you are curious:

```
def min_in_limits(value,list):
    new_val = min(list, key=lambda x: float(abs(float(x)-float(value)))<0.5)
    return new_val
```

Your lambda function is fine, but notice that when you apply min(data=, key=), the key arguement inside allows you to customise in which logic you want your data to be sorted (read [here](https://thepythonguru.com/python-builtin-functions/min/)). Because your lambda function returns a list with value`[True, False, False]`, applying `min` on `[True, False, False]` returns the last item `False` in the array, which corresponds to value=11.

You can examine the bahaviour of `min()` yourself, simply:

```
a=min(True,False,False)
b=max(True,False,False)
print (a,b)
```

gives your:

```
False True
```